# Web Scraping problem with downloading file - link automatically downloads PDF file but I can't save it correctly

Tags: python, pdf, web-scraping

I have a link that when pressed automatically downloads a PDF file

The link looks something like this:

""https://u14350383.ct.sendgrid.net/ls/click?upn=pmcnQ2-2FzMlkei0-2F............"

There is no PDF extension at the end.

My code is very simple:

```
reponse = requests.get(url)
if not os.path.isfile(filePath):
    fp = open(filePath, 'wb')
    fp.write(reponse.content)(decode=True))
    fp.close()
```

I tried writing it to a PDF file with response.content and response.text but each time I get an "object not callable" error. When I print the text/content of the response I get the PDF file, how can I  actually save it?

Answer (score 2):

**fp.write(reponse.content)(decode=True))** is wrong and don't try to save bytes content as string. result will be strange

***Edit***

```
   reponse = requests.get(url)
   if not os.path.isfile(filePath):
      fp = open(filePath, 'wb')
      fp.write(reponse.content)
      fp.close()
```